# CMake Dlibdotnet.native Build Error

Tags: c#, c++, .net, cmake, dlib

am facing some problem when i build dlibdotnet.native using cmake. Please help me to Soleve this issue. Error resut here.

> CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:7 (if):
>   Policy CMP0054 is not set: Only interpret if() arguments as variables or
>   keywords when unquoted. Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0054" for policy
>   details. Use the cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this
>   warning.
>
> variables like "MSVC" will no longer be dereferenced when the policy
>   is set to NEW. Since the policy is not set the OLD behavior will be used.
>   This warning is for project developers. Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
>
> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (add_subdirectory):
>   add_subdirectory given source "/dlib" which is not an existing directory.

Windows 10, CMake 3.12

[dlibdotnet Github Link here](https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/DlibDotNet)

Comment: Have you installed [the dependencies listed here](https://github.com/takuya-takeuchi/DlibDotNet) correctly?

Comment: yes i do. i din't made any changes to source code. just build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found this solution so easier than CMake GUI

> Open DlibDotNet\src\DlibDotNet.Native in command prompt
>   Type the following code in a console:
>   mkdir build
>   cd build
>   cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" ^
>         -DDLIB_PATH=D:/Works/Lib/DLib/19.8 ^
>         ..
>   Type the following code in a console:
>   cmake --build . --config Release
>   Or
>
> cmake --build . --config Debug
>   Binary files will be in build\Release or build\Debug